# Compile (but do not run) a Python script

Tags: python, syntax-checking

I want to check a script for syntax errors. In both 2.x and 3.x, how can I compile the script without running it?

Comment: @sukhbir: You're right, but I just realized the answer, and it isn't given in that thread.

Comment: @asmeurer: Yes it is, the answer that you posted is in that question.

Comment: Compiling and syntax checking are different things, really. You want to syntax check, The answer is in the other thread. You *ask* how to compile it, which is a different question, you should really change the topic.

Comment: @Lennart:  Is there a way to check syntax without compiling?  I suppose you could use something like pylint, but in Python compiling is such a fast operation that you might as well do that and make truly sure that everything works.

Comment: Using pylint or pyflakes will find *more* problems than compiling will.

Comment: @Lennart:  Unfortunately, Pylint/Pyflakes currently do not satisfy one of the conditions of my original question, which is that it must run in Python 3.

Comment: This is true, but also just a matter of time.

Comment: flake8 (https://github.com/pycqa/flake8/blob/master/docs/source/index.rst)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[py_compile — Compile Python source files](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html)

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('my_script.py')
```

Comment: Before you use this approach, take a look at Mark Johnson's highly voted answer to make this a command-line execution without additional python.

Answer (score 402):

```
python -m py_compile script.py
```

Comment: You can expand on this with `find` and `xargs` to check directories.

Here's how to run it on your `src/` dir:
`find src -type f -name '*.py' | xargs -n1 python3 -m py_compile`

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#using-on-cmdline and https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html  (In particular, see the discussion of `main()`.)

Comment: This is a great answer, but note there is a similar one `python -m compileall some/dir/` that will recurse unlike `py_compile`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/) to find syntax errors as well as more subtle errors, such as accessing undefined variables in some rarely-used conditional branch.

Answer (score 9):

One way is to do something like this (for `test.py`):

```
python -c "__import__('compiler').parse(open('test.py').read())"
```

This works for Python 2.x.